# Java try/catch error with parameter of class build

Tags: java, excel, class, object, try-catch

I am still pretty new to coding and am working on a project where the idea is to look over an excel spreadsheet and put then create a class that builds a statement for each row's information. I have the following code below.

```
public class Message {

// information from excel
String excelPath = "./data/RecruiterData.xlsx";
String sheetName = "Sheet1";
ExcelUtils excel = new ExcelUtils(excelPath, sheetName);
int excelRowCount = excel.getRowCount();


// build recruiter class
public static Recruiter[] buildRecruiter = {
    try {
    // this needs to be a for each cell filled in excel, create an instance of recruiter
    for (int i = 0; i < excelRowCount; i++) {
        new Recruiter(excel.getCellData(1, i), excel.getCellData(2, i), excel.getCellData(3, i), excel.getCellData(4, i));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");

   }
}
```

But yet it is giving me a bunch of errors. The first error is in the public static Recruiter[] where right at the end of that line, it says ; expect } expected.

Next, there are errors with my try catch statement just saying unexpected token.

Finally, it is giving each parameter in the new Recruiter line an error saying unhandled exception: java.io.IOException. I was not sucessful trying to find help online so I thought I would ask about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's not how methods are defined in Java. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: I think you need to declare your static variables and then have a separate block of static code that initialize the variable.  I don't do this very much but here's an example.

Comment: You'll also need to understand the difference between static and instance fields/methods.

Comment: @ChengThao I think the OP is accustomed to Javascript and is trying to write a method. (but it is hard to tell)

Comment: @tgdavies Yes, I should have seen that by the name ```buildRecruiter``` which is an action.  Otherwise, it would be a noun like ```recruiter```.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm i think your error is in the method declaration

```
   public class Message {

// information from excel
static String excelPath = "./data/RecruiterData.xlsx";
static String sheetName = "Sheet1";
static ExcelUtils excel = new ExcelUtils(excelPath, sheetName);
static int excelRowCount = excel.getRowCount();


// build recruiter class
public static Recruiter[] buildRecruiter () {
    //in java methods are declarated for that way [scope] [instance] data_type name ([params]) { [body; return data_type]}
    //next if you declare static your function all fields must be static too or change te method declaration to public or private 
    try {
    // this needs to be a for each cell filled in excel, create an instance of recruiter
    for (int i = 0; i < excelRowCount; i++) {
        new Recruiter(excel.getCellData(1, i), excel.getCellData(2, i), excel.getCellData(3, i), excel.getCellData(4, i));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");

   }
}
}
```